# No critical points around strict minimum

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Let $f :\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be twice continuously differentiable and $\nabla f(x) = 0$ and $H_f(x)$ positive definite. Is it true that $\nabla f$ does not have any other roots in an environment around $x$?

I seem to be missing something trivial here. I believe it's true. By the conditions, $x$ is a strict local minimum/maximum. I'd like to suppose that there would be a sequence of strict minima/maxima converging to $x$ otherwise but where is the contradiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is strictly convex in a convex neighbourhood of $x$, because the Hessian is positive definite there.  The gradient of a strictly convex function is $0$ only at a global minimu, which is unique.

Comment: Oh yes, of course, thank you! Do you know if the assertion stays correct if it were only known that $f \in C^1$ and $x$ is a strict local minimum?

Comment: No, e.g try $f(x) = x^2 + 3 x^3 \sin(1/x)$.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!